# Novel in which a killer says "There. There." as she or he stabs people

Tags: identification-request

I have a vague memory of a book in which a killer (perhaps a serial killer) says "There. There." as they stab someone. I think the killer is female, but I am not certain of that. It even might be some means of killing other than stabbing. I think the killing is retribution for some kind of abuse. Note that I am NOT referring to Randy Lenz in *Infinite Jest* (reading that section of the book is what dredged up the memory).

Additional details: the book was a novel, written in English ten or more years ago, I believe. Not SF or fantasy, not noir. Set in the contemporary US.

Comment: Welcome to Literature! Can you remember any more details about this book - when did you read it, how old was it, where/when was it set, was it in English or translated, was it a novel or short story or comic, was it sci-fi or realistic? *Any* little detail can help, and you might be surprised at how many details you can jog out of your memory!